# Swap rows with columns (transposition) of a matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array, swap

For instance I have a matrix like this:

```
|1 2 3|    
|4 5 6|
|7 8 9|
```

and I need it to convert into a matrix like this:

```
|1 4 7|    
|2 5 8|
|3 6 9|
```

What is the best and optimal way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See article: [Transpose An Array In JavaScript and jQuery](http://www.shamasis.net/2010/02/transpose-an-array-in-javascript-and-jquery)

```js
function transpose(a) {

  // Calculate the width and height of the Array
  var w = a.length || 0;
  var h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;

  // In case it is a zero matrix, no transpose routine needed.
  if(h === 0 || w === 0) { return []; }

  /**
   * @var {Number} i Counter
   * @var {Number} j Counter
   * @var {Array} t Transposed data is stored in this array.
   */
  var i, j, t = [];

  // Loop through every item in the outer array (height)
  for(i=0; i<h; i++) {

    // Insert a new row (array)
    t[i] = [];

    // Loop through every item per item in outer array (width)
    for(j=0; j<w; j++) {

      // Save transposed data.
      t[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
  }

  return t;
}

console.log(transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach adds a new element to each array in your application! Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/gj6q1k0j/

Comment: @vektor your input should look like [[1,2,3,4]]

Also, you should loop like


`for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
`
If you plan on doing for..in

But yes, it is probably a bad idea to extend Array.
I'll change example.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. My point was that the original solution broke all the Arrays...

Answer (score 82):

[DuckDucking](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=transpose+javascript+array+in+one+line&t=h_&ia=web) turned up [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725092857/http://www.codesuck.com/2012/02/transpose-javascript-array-in-one-line.html) by [Ken](https://www.blogger.com/profile/04177812784911881478). Surprisingly, it's even more concise and complete than [Nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330565/nikita-rybak)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4492689/623735). It retrieves column and row lengths implicitly within the guts of `map()`.

```js
function transpose(a) {
    return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function(c) {
        return a.map(function(r) { return r[c]; });
    });
}

console.log(transpose([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]));
```

[image: [[1,4,5],[2,5,8],[7,8,9]]

Comment: Object.keys isnt supported by IEX<9 so in that case i'd stick to one of the other answers if you need to provide support for that.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't noticed that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: though there is a fix for that detailed here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @hobs can you explain what `a[0]` is?

Comment: @AlanH it's the first inner array in your array of arrays. This inner array is the first row of your 2D array (matrix) if you stored your data in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). [The docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) and other [SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15995788/623735) give more detail.

Answer (score 7):

Just like in any other language:

```
int[][] copy = new int[columns][rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
        copy[j][i] = original[i][j];
    }
}
```

You just have to construct the 2D array differently in JS. Like this:

```js
function transpose(original) {
    var copy = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < original[i].length; ++j) {
            // skip undefined values to preserve sparse array
            if (original[i][j] === undefined) continue;
            // create row if it doesn't exist yet
            if (copy[j] === undefined) copy[j] = [];
            // swap the x and y coords for the copy
            copy[j][i] = original[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

console.log(transpose([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]));
```

Comment: Unlike the other solution, this one works for jagged arrays i.e. if you change [4,5,6] to [4,5,6,0], this solution still works. Others don't.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to comment (wtf.), so I need to post [Ken's updated version](http://www.codesuck.com/2012/02/transpose-javascript-array-in-one-line.html) as a separate answer:

```
function transpose(a) {
    return a[0].map(function (_, c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compact version of [Hobs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241545/2237382) using arrow functions from ES6:

```
function transpose(matrix) {
    return Object.keys(matrix[0])
        .map(colNumber => matrix.map(rowNumber => rowNumber[colNumber]));
}
```