# Filling JQuery Mobile Scrollview elements in vertical order

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a menu just like Windows 8 Start Menu (Metro style) using JQuery Mobile.

I'm going to use JQuery Mobile `Scrollview` for this purpose. ([see this example](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html))

`Scrollview` adds elemets by Horizontal order (like the image below)

[image: Current]
*Above image is real screenshot*

But I want to add elemets to the `Scrollview` by vertical order (like the image below)

[image: Goal]
*Above Image is NOT real. It's my goal. (I have created it in MS Paint :P )*

**So, my question is: How to change adding order of the `Scrollview` to vertical order? (like the second image)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agreement with this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/to-swap-rows-with-columns-of-matrix-in-javascript-or-jquery)

you should move items on the list in order to reorder the desired sequence (eg translation matrices), once you get what you can eliminate the above list and recreate it again, after which the mobile jquery apply its effects.

I tried this (using your example, i've copied the page on local), it is not nice but you get the idea.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


var arr = $.map( $(".threeByThree").children().text(), function(n){
   return n;
 });

var result = [];
var results;

while(arr.length){

    transform(arr.splice(0,8));     
}   

function transform(arr){

    var a = [
        [arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]],
        [arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]],
        [arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]]
    ],

    w = a.length ? a.length : 0,
    h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;

  if(h === 0 || w === 0) { return []; }

  var i, j, t = [];

  for(i=0; i<h; i++) {

    t[i] = [];

    for(j=0; j<w; j++) {

       t[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
  }

results = result += t;
result += t; 

var rm = ',';

results = $.grep(results, function(value) {
  return value != rm;
});

}

$('.threeByThree').children().remove();

$.each(results, function(index, value){$('.threeByThree').append('<div class="square">'+value+'</div>');

});

});

</script>
```

and

```
.threeByThree > .ui-scrollview-view {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

is just a test to improve.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm getting an empty scrollview using your code ( see this : http://i.imgur.com/kADJF.png ) Can you apply your changes to this file ( http://pastie.org/4043814 ) and send me the changed file? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but please use **horizontal** scrollview instead of vertical scrollview in your example. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahdi, the example is one way (bad) to change the order of items, then I think you can appilcare other effects. I know jQuery Mobile, and the scroll does not work locally. This is the example I wanted to change order factors [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukfCD/)

Comment: Since I'm using a programming language (ASP.NET or PHP) to download RSS feeds, I think I also should make elements in the right order using ASP.NET or PHP. What do you think?