# How to access a element in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have a JS array:

```
a = ["a",["b","c"]]
```

How I can access string "b" in this array? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is `a[1][0]`

```
alert(a[1][0]) // "b"
```

Answer (score 7):

You index into an array like this:

```
a[1][0]
```

Arrays are accessed using their integer indexes. Since this is an array inside an array, you use `[1]` to access the inner array, then get the first item in that array with `[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

As there is an alternative way also to access the element in the array which is:

```
a['1']['0']  //"b"
```

as array is internally an object so think indexes is a property of that object so

```
a = ["a",["b","c"]]
```

can be internally and object keys or property are internally transfer to string so:

```
a = {
    '0' : "a",
    '1' : ["b", "c"]
}
```

this also can refactor to:

```
a = {
    '0' : "a",
    '1' : {
        '0' : "b",
        '1' : "c"
    }
}
```

so we can access that index as:

```
a['1']['0']
```

this will give the value as `b`.