# How to access element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vba

I work in VBA. I converted Javascript Array to VB Array. To be honest it is not 100% vba array...It looks as in attached picture.

I would like to access directly individual items from this array/list. I tried:

1. `Msgbox ConvertedArray(1,1)`  doesn't work
2. `Msgbox ConvertedArray(1).Item("1")` doesn't work

All what is working is counting the size of this "array" by writing

```
 For each Item in ConvertedArray
 ItemNo = ItemNo+1
 Next
```

Do you have any clue what is wrong with that array?

[image]

Comment: `ConvertedArray(1)(1)` or  `ConvertedArray(1).Item(1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a element in JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15995780/608639)

Answer (score 0):

its the multidimensional array, you will need to access it through index element and not by item string

```
ConvertedArray(1)(1)
```

or

```
ConvertedArray(1).Item(1)
```

should work for you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Normal array has diffrent structure. Example: arr(0):   -arr(0,0)  -arr(0,1) - arr(0,2), arr(1): -arr(1,0), -arr(1,1) etc.

Comment: could you provide your code where you have created/Converted  ConvertedArray