# iterate JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. How do I iterate a JSON result that has convert into javascript object?

```
const url = 'https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/tickers?pair=XBTMYR';
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    //.then(json => console.log(json))
    .then(function(data) {
     let bp = data.tickers
     console.log(bp.timestamp)
    })
```

the object results are

```
[ { timestamp: 1500349843208,
    bid: '9762.00',
    ask: '9780.00',
    last_trade: '9760.00',
    rolling_24_hour_volume: '325.277285',
    pair: 'XBTMYR' } ]
```

I just want to print out the "timestamp" key. Thanks.

Comment: Try data.timestamp

Comment: return "undefined"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a element in JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995780/how-to-access-a-element-in-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2):

Put key and then the object.

```
console.log(bp[0].timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an array, as such you can iterate it by index or by using `for` or `.forEach`.

```
for(var i=0; i<bp.length;i++) {
    var element= bp[i];
}
```

Each element in your array is an object. To access the timestamp of that element use `["timestamp"]` or `.timestamp`

```
for(var i=0; i< bp.length; i++) {
    var element = bp[i];
    var timestamp = element.timestamp;
    var ts= element["timestamp"];
}
```

To get the first time stamp use simply use `b[0].timestamp`.