# How to get object value separated by type?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jsonpath

I have an Object like this.
I got the "apple" in the following code and an object.

```
 {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "name": "apple"
 }
```

```
var name_Json_obj = Json_obj.name;
console.log(name_Json_obj);
```

However, in this type of object I can not get "Orange". or "Melon".

How to get "Orange". or "Melon".

```
   {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {  "@type": "ImageObject",
           "name": "Orange"  },
      
        {  "@type": "VideoObject",
           "name": "Melon"   }
        ]
    }
```

```
var name_first_Json_obj = Json_obj.???;
```

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:jsonpath] but your code (`var name_first_Json_obj = Json_obj.???`) is using regular JavaScript accessors. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995780/how-to-access-a-element-in-javascript-array

Answer (score 1):

Since there is `@` you can't use *dot notation*, so use *bracket notation*:

`Json_obj['@graph'][0].name`

```js
var Json_obj = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [{
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "name": "Orange"
    },

    {
      "@type": "VideoObject",
      "name": "Melon"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Json_obj['@graph'][0].name)
```

Comment: Square brackets (`[]`) are not braces (`{}`)

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, not fluent English :D