# Fetch Two urls Java script

Tags: javascript, fetch, call

How to call data from this array??
I have to add two values from others urls.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAAFo.png)

```html
<table id="sales_table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="sales_item_title"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="sales_item"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  async function init(){
  try{
      const results = await Promise.all([

        fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=PLN').then((response)=> response.json()),

        fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist')
        .then((response)=> response.json()),

      ].map(promise=>promise.catch(error=>console.error)));

      console.log(results);
      document.querySelector('#sales_item').innerHTML = results.0.PLN

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  init();
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a element in JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995780/how-to-access-a-element-in-javascript-array)

Comment: @Siguza Sorry, but I want to display data from both API and add them.
They are called 0 and 1, and i dont know how to call them in document.querySelector('#sales_item').innerHTML = results.data([1][0]).PLN

Answer (score 1):

You return two objects and you have access to the object by key. In your example PLN . Then use : `object.PLN`.

```js
async function init() {
    const first = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=PLN')
    .then((response)=> response.json());

    const second = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist')
     .then((response)=> response.json());

    let merged = {...first, ...second};
    console.log(merged);    
    console.log('PLN:',merged.PLN)
}

init()
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('some problems: ' + e.message);
    });
```