# Building the HTML table - columns first

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have the following 2-dimensional structure (1) (with different number of columns):

```
|T11  T12  T13     |
|T21  T22  T23  T24|
|T31  T32          |
```

and I would like to build the HTML table with this data, but in the following way (2):

```
|T11  T21  T31|
|T12  T22  T32|
|T13  T23     |
|     T24     |
```

So actually using matrix transposition doing this is straightforward.

BUT if I am extracting the data from more complicated JSON object and parsing this on-the-fly to get to get this (1), I would prefer just to loop over the (1) somehow to get the output (2) without using transposition.

Could you please help me to understand the best method to achieve it?

Comment: And you want to do this with jQuery?

Comment: can you show us some example json that you will parse and example html code of an output table that should result from that and a jsfiddle to work with?

Comment: I really think transposition is the way to go. And it's easily done. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4492703/2335006

Comment: Or, just build the table normally and then display it in a transposed way with CSS... http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n9pfy/4/