# Convert columns to rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, transpose

I have read this [Swap rows with columns (transposition) of a matrix in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/to-swap-rows-with-columns-of-matrix-in-javascript-or-jquery) However, it did not work for me (because I still stupi).

There are numbers of arrays each as individual colum like that:

```
id [1, 2, 3]
caption [one, two, three]
title [One, Two, Three]
```

I want to convert columns to row:

```
arr= [1, one, One]
```

...

Some code

```
        var res = [];

        for(i in this.fields) {

            for(j in this.fields[i].value) {

                res[j][i] = this.fields[i].value[j];

            }

        }
```

it give me "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object "

In php this method works fine, but could somebody point me how to do it in js. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE for simplication

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = [];

arr[6][0] = 5;
/*
Exception: can't convert undefined to object
@Scratchpad/1:4
 */
```

When we scan common string we iterate with indexes like 0-0, 0-1, 0-2 until end-of-row when starts again 1-0 and so on. But here I need 0-0, 1-0, 2-0 end of col and again 1-0, 1-1, 1-1 ...

UPDATE for "this". Just add a cople of lines:

```
                console.log(this.fields[i].value[j]);
                console.log('indexes: i='+i, 'j='+j);
```

and as could you see there are no undefined values

```
4
indexes: i=0 j=0
1
indexes: i=1 j=0
1
indexes: i=2 j=0
one
indexes: i=3 j=0
One
indexes: i=4 j=0
```

Comment: What is `this` in this context?

Comment: Show the `this.fields` structure.

Comment: As described above this is 2-x array in fields[i].value[j]. Just I want to how enforce JS write a value to arbitrary index of array.

Comment: @kostya sorry, can't see where it is described on post above.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your source code. We don´t know how your `this.fields` value looks like, but for the sake of your code snippet let it look like that:

```
this.fields = [
    { value: [1, 2, 3] },
    { value: [4, 5, 6] },
    { value: [7, 8, 9] }
]
```

If your `this.fields` variable looks like that, you are not so far away from the solution. Your error message says `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`, so I am guessing your variable does not look like described.

When we transform your data in a form that looks like my example, your are not so far away from the solution in your code snippet. The problem is `res` does not know, that its second dimension is supposed to consist of arrays, because you never defined that. We can fix that by adding `if(i === 0) res[j] = [];`.

So with the described structure and our little fix, it should work:

```
    var res = [];

    for(i in this.fields) {

        for(j in this.fields[i].value) {

            if(i === 0) res[j] = [];
            res[j][i] = this.fields[i].value[j];

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure one error is within the loop itself. On the first iteration `res[j]` exists, but inside the inner loop `res[j][i]` is not defined and will throw an error. You could fix it by checking if the element already exists:

```
var res = [];

for(i in this.fields) {

    for(j in this.fields[i].value) {

        if( !res[j] ) { res[j] = []; }

        res[j][i] = this.fields[i].value[j];

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I did, but without condition and getting all elements empty except the last one. Thanks again. Now it works.