# Changing rows to columns javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to change the rows into columns of an array.

```
[
  [1],
  [1,2],
  [1,2,3],
  [4,2,3],
  [4,5,3],
  [4,5,6]
]
```

to 
   [
     [1,1,1,4,4,4],
     [2,2,2,5,5],
     [3,3,3,6]
   ]

I tried

```
var res = [];

    for(i in this.fields) {

        for(j in this.fields[i].value) {

            if(i === 0) res[j] = [];
            res[j][i] = this.fields[i].value[j];

        }

    }
```

this gives me empty set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To swap rows with columns of matrix in javascript (or jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/to-swap-rows-with-columns-of-matrix-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: your to code isn't showing

Comment: the answers in that post only gives me the first array,

Comment: @darthbith expected result is different to in that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking looks a little weird because you have different lengths and you're ignoring *undefined* values, but it is still achievable.

Don't use `for..in` loops for *Array*, use a normal `for`. Also, you'll need to know how many items you'll have in your new parent *Array*, which is the *max* of the lengths of the original child *Arrays*.

```
var arrR = [ // will refer to "down" and "across" as in this literal
        [1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ];
function r2c(arr) {
    var arrC = [], // next get the longest sub-array length
        x = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (e) {return e.length;})),
        y = arr.length,
        i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {   // this is the loop "down"
        arrC[i] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j) // and this is the loop "across"
            if (i in arr[j])
                arrC[i].push(arr[j][i]);
    }
    return arrC;
}
var arrC = r2c(arrR);
/* [
    [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 2, 2, 5, 5],
    [3, 3, 3, 6]
] */
```

You should still consider if you're happy with `[[1], [1, 2], [1]]` becoming `[[1, 1, 1], [2]]`, which I would consider unexpected (the position of `2` is completely lost), but seems to be what you intend.

Answer (score 3):

Create this function:

```
function transpose(arr) {
        return Object.keys(arr[0]).map(function (c) {
            return arr.map(function (r) {
                return r[c];
            });
        });
    }
```

and then:

var transposedArray = transpose(originalArray);

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Pauls but doesn't need to get the max length first:

```
function transpose(arr) {

  // Loop over arrays as long as one has values
  // Arrays should be contiguous, may fail if sparse
  for (var result = [], i=0, more; more; i++) {
    more = false;

    // Get the ith element of each array (if there is one)
    for (var j=0, jLen=arr.length; j<jLen; j++) {

      // Don't add missing members
      if (arr[j].hasOwnProperty(i)) {

        // Add array for result if not already there
        result[i] = result[i] || [];

        // Do transpose
        result[i][j] = arr[j][i];

        // Only keep going while there is data
        more = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

BTW, a fixed version of your original function is:

```
function transpose2(fields) {
    // Make sure the result array is initialised
    var res = [];

    // Don't forget to keep counters local - declare them
    // I've removed *this* as it's a plain function, use it if 
    // it's an instance method
    for(var i in fields) {

        // Values are read directly, there is no "value" accessor
        for(var j in fields[i]) {

            // Don't rely on order of enumeration - may not start at 0
            if(!res[j]) res[j] = [];

            // Do the transpose
            res[j][i] = fields[i][j];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

But as noted above, for..in is not liked for arrays, particularly as there are many libraries that extend built-ins like Array.prototype so you will traverse those properties too. But if you're cool with that, this is a good way to deal with sparse arrays. You can add a *hasOwnProperty* test to avoid inherited enumerables.

Note also that the order of enumeration isn't necessarily from '0' or in any particular order, hence changed way of initialising `res[j]`.