# 2-dimensions array "mirroring" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to "mirror" (like seen in a mirror) a 2-d array.
The array looks like that:

```
array1 = [
  ['a','b','c'],
  ['d','e','f'],
  ['g','h','i'],
  ['j','k','l']
];
```

I'd like to create a new array which values "mirror" the first array values, like that:

```
array2 = [
  ['a','e','i'],
  ['b','f','j'],
  ['c','g','k'],
  ['d','h','l']
];
```

Been trying a couple of thing with reverse() but I cannot find a solution.

**Edit**: in this case "mirror" means something similar to Cramer's Rule:
http://www.1728.org/cramer4d.png (see diagonals)

**Edit**: My bad, I should have copy-proofed my post. 
The second array should like:

```
array2 = [
  ['a','d','g','j'],
  ['b','e','h', 'k'],
  ['c','f','i', 'l']
];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/to-swap-rows-with-columns-of-matrix-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @user2717954 that does not look like the question posted by OP.

Comment: Are you sure that the output shouldn't be a 3x4 matrix (that would then be the transpose of the original 4x3 matrix)

Comment: My bad. Fixed that in my question.

Comment: Tested now, and @user2717954 's link solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is flatten the array of arrays, with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this

```
var array1 = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['j', 'k', 'l']
];

var flatArray = array1.reduce(function(result, currentArray) {
    return result.concat(currentArray);
}, []);

console.log(flatArray);
# [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' ]
```

And then, for every element, get the element after the length of the individual arrays, like this

```
var rows = array1.length,
    cols = array1[0].length + 1,
    result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols - 1; j += 1) {
        temp.push(flatArray[i + (j * cols)]);
    }
    result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ [ 'a', 'e', 'i' ],
  [ 'b', 'f', 'j' ],
  [ 'c', 'g', 'k' ],
  [ 'd', 'h', 'l' ] ]
```