# Way to multiply each element of one array to PARTS of another?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I am newbie in programming and try to find out how to multiply

```
[1,1,0]
```

to

```
[4,9,7,2,1,6]
```

for the next result output

```
[4,9,7,2,0,0]
```

As you see I want to multiply each value of [1,1,0] array to each two of second array by shifting in them

```
[1..] * [4,9..] = [4,9]
[.1.] * [.7,2.] = [7,2]
[..0] * [..1,6] = [0,0]
```

As example in js i writed something like

```
var firstArray = [1,1,0];
var secondArray = [4,9,7,2,1,6];
var shift = secondArray / firstArray;
var startpos = 0;
var outArray = [];

for(i=0; i< firstArray.length; i++){
    for(z=i; z< shift+i; z++){
        outArray.push(firstArray[i] * secondArray[z]);
    }
}

console.log(outArray);
```

It may be in python

Comment: You are looking for a solution in python only or in javascript as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse `zip` and list slicing:

```
a = [1, 1, 0]
b = [4, 9, 7, 2, 1, 6]

shift = len(b) // len(a)  # use / in Python 2
li = []
for num_a, num_b1, num_b2 in zip(a, b[::shift], b[1::shift]):
    li.extend([num_a * num_b1, num_a * num_b2])

print(li)
# [4, 9, 7, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: For what is `shift` used in this example?

Comment: @Richy as the slicing "skip" argument,  I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you guys! You are awesome

Comment: @DeepSpace now it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could use a more functional approach by using

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for iterating the factors and returning a new array,
- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for adding a part result after multiplying to the result set,
- [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), for getting only two elements of the values array,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for multiplying the part array with the given factor,
- at least use an array as start value for `reduce`.

```js
var factors = [1, 1, 0],
    values = [4, 9, 7, 2, 1, 6],
    result = factors.reduce(
        (r, f, i) => r.concat(
            values
                .slice(i * 2, (i + 1) * 2)
                .map(v => f * v)
        ),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as a standard matrix multiplication by making your inputs 2D arrays.

I got the multiplication algorithm from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205510/5710637

The calculation would now look like:

```
[1,0,0]   [4,9]   [4,9]
[0,1,0] * [7,2] = [7,2]
[0,0,0]   [1,6]   [0,0]
```

```js
function multiplyMatrices(m1, m2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
            }
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var in1 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]];
var in2 = [[4, 9], [7, 2], [1, 6]]

console.log(multiplyMatrices(in1, in2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Iterate over first array so that you get a number to multiply.
2. Then extract two elements from the target array and multiply, store the result in res array.

```js
var mul = [1,1,0];


    var target = [4,9,7,2,1,6];
    var start = 0;
    var res = [];
    mul.forEach(function(v,i) {
      var arr = target.slice(start, start+2);//from start index extract two 
                                             //elements
      arr.forEach(function(val,i) {
        res.push(v * val);
      });
      start += 2;
    });

    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on array2 and use one var for incrementing index of array1 for each two elements and then multiply current element of array1 with element from array2 that has index as that var.

```js
var a1 = [1,1,0];
var a2 = [4,9,7,2,1,6];

var j = 0;
var result = a2.map(function(e, i) {
  if(i % 2 == 0 && i != 0) j++
  return e * a1[j];
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python` you can use the following code. I'm assuming the length of the second array is larger and it is divisible by the length of the shorter array

```
def multiply(a, b):
    x, y = len(a), len(b)                        # Find lengths
    assert x % y == 0                            
    n = x / y
    result = [a[i] * b[i / n] for i in range(x)] # For each index in a, calculate the appropriate element in output by multiplying with relevant part
    print result
```