# How to pair elements between multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which can contain a different number of arrays. What I want to do is to match all arrays in order of key not value, and produce a new array for each row created, something like this

```
var arr = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5]
]
```

The result I need

```
var arr = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5]]
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean convert rows into columns and columns into rows?

Comment: through the use of code ... have at it then come back when you're stuck :p

Comment: `const rotate = a => Object.keys(a[0]).map(c => a.map(r => r[c] ));` - oh, wait, you don't want to rotate the array, you just want an array of arrays of the same value?

Comment: your sample input and output are actually ambiguous ... what if the input is `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` what output would you expect?

Comment: Or better yet `const fn=a=>a[0].map((c, i)=>a.map(r=>r[i]));`

Answer (score 1):

**I think here is what you are looking for.**

```js
var arr = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4,5]
];

var res = arr.reduce((x, y) => {
  for(let i in y) {
    x[i] ? x[i].push(y[i]) : x[i] = [y[i]];
  }
  
  return x;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: nevermind my comment :p

Comment: @JaromandaX He wants in order of keys not values.
His query was "**I want to do is to match all arrays in order of key not value**"

Comment: I misread your code :p

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are looking for this one. It retrieves column and row lengths implicitly within the map(). Source [[Swap rows with columns (transposition) of a matrix in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/swap-rows-with-columns-transposition-of-a-matrix-in-javascript])

```js
function transpose(a) {
    return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function(c) {
        return a.map(function(r) { return r[c]; });
    });
}
      


        console.log(transpose([
            [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5]
        ]));
```