# Vue/PHP - Parse JSON string as table

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to parse a JSON string that my Laravel application serves to my Vue view. The JSON string can look like this:

```
{  
   "1":[ { "row":"Some text here on first column." },
         { "row":"And more text. Second row." },
         { "row":"Text!" }
   ],
   "2":[ { "row":"2nd column text." },
         { "row":"" }
   ],
   "3":[ { "row":"Even more text. But on the third column." }
   ]
}
```

Things to note here:

1. The "1", "2", and "3" refers to columns. So in above examples, I have 3 columns.
2. Each "row" refers to a row within the column.

I am trying to parse the string as a table, like: https://jsfiddle.net/59bz2hqs/1/

This is what I have now:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr v-for="row in this.content">
                 <td>{{row}}</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>
   <div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {

                content: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            Event.$on("document-was-processed", content => {
                this.content = content;          
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Now above simply prints out the actual JSON string. Can anyone help me out on how to actually parse the content?

## Edit

Thinking a bit more about this. I am actually not quite sure if my JSON string layout can even support my desired output.

Maybe like something below? Not quite sure.

```
{ "1":[
      { "text":"Some text here on first column."},
      { "text":"2nd column text."},
      { "text":"Even more text. But on the third column"}
   ],
   "2":[
      { "text":"And more text. Second row." },
      { "text":"" },
      { "text":"" }
   ],
   "3":[
      { "text":"Text!"},
      { "text":""},
      { "text":""}
   ]}
```

Then something like:

```
<table class="text-left w-full border-collapse m-3">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-gray-100">

      <th v-for="(item, idx) in this.content" class="p-1">
        {{idx}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, rid) in this.content">
      <td v-for="(col, cid) in row">{{ col.text }} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428705/1891624) your data before rendering it.

This is my dummy code

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataTable: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    // Instead of fetching your content I put it in a local variable
    let content = JSON.parse(`{  
   "1":[ { "row":"Some text here on first column." },
         { "row":"And more text. Second row." },
         { "row":"Text!" }
   ],
   "2":[ { "row":"2nd column text." },
         { "row":"" }
   ],
   "3":[ { "row":"Even more text. But on the third column." }
   ]
    }`);
    // Transform object in array of its values
    let data = Object.values(content);
    let colsLength = data.map(r => r.length);
    let maxNumCols = Math.max.apply(Math, colsLength);
    let colsArraySchema = Array.apply(null, Array(maxNumCols)).map((r, i) => i);
    this.dataTable = colsArraySchema.map((col, i) => data.map(row => row[i]));

    // For debug.
    console.log(content);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(colsLength);
    console.log(maxNumCols);
    console.log(this.dataTable);
  }
};
</script>
```

Now you can render the dataTable variable in your template.
(Take care that you row array could contain undefined values)

```
<template>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in dataTable" :key="index">
        <td v-for="(cell, index) in row" :key="index">
          <span v-if="cell">{{cell["row"]}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

You can see a live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-json-transpose-dt915

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is very nice! Do you mind checking my **edit** of my OP? I propose another JSON string format - I am not sure if this is better? The JSON string is created by my backend (PHP, Laravel), so my 2nd JSON string requires me to change a bit of backend code.

Comment: Just a question to your answer: I tested with some other content. The `console.log(data)` returns `1: Array(8), 2: Array(52), 3: Array(33)`. However, for some reason the `console.log(this.dataTable)` output is: `0: (3), 1: (3), 2: (3)` - for some reason, it only outputs 3 rows? While one of the columns have 52.

Comment: Can you share your new JSON content with 52 columns?

Comment: using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/swap-rows-with-columns-transposition-of-a-matrix-in-javascript/13241545#13241545) transpose function seems to give me another output. - this outputs: `(8) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3),`

But this only prints out 8 rows, where I still have a total of 52 in the "longest" column.

Comment: I guess it only prints out 8 rows, because my **first** column is no longer than 8 elements? Then it never processes the rest (using above `transpose` function)

Comment: Answer updated. The first version uses the number of elements in the JSON to determine the number of rows. In this new version, I calculate the row number of the columns from the max length of the first element of the JSON content.

Comment: Thank you SO much! You've literally freed me from hours and hours of debugging and headbanging! Really appreciate you taking your time to help me out :) It works perfectly!