# Transform columns into rows using Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pivot

Hoping someone can assist. I am using Material-UI table, something similar to [Basic Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#basic-table) but need a solution to convert this type of table from columns to rows, basically something similar to this: [Transpose data from columns to rows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744)

Can anyone point me to any examples where this is possible within material-ui. Basically need to perform a pivot.

Comment: This might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492678/swap-rows-with-columns-transposition-of-a-matrix-in-javascript