# Swap row and column of multidimensional array with any length

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimension array with any length inside as below:

Array = `[[4, 9, 4], [4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 2, 7], [9, 1, 7, 8, 11], [1, 7, 3, 6, 4]]`

And I want this array to be made as below:

Array =  `[[4, 4, 3, 9, 1], [9, 9, 5, 1, 7], [4,2,2,7,3], [7,8,6], [11,4]]`

Saw many different solutions in Stack Overflow, but all are showing for same dimension array swap. So if you know my question answer in easy formatting of code then please let me know. Otherwise for loop will take long time as well as the length will also increase.

I tried following code:

```
function transpose(a) {
    return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) {
    return a.map(function (r) { return r[c];});});
}
```

But this is giving simple 3 x 3 array. But I need multidimensional array as in description.

Comment: The solutions in the linked question don't require the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: @Barmar The solutions that don't require same number of rows and columns don't take into account that the width of the matrix can be greater than `a[0].length`, as in this example

Comment: Actually it seems one of them does but that is hard to find, it would be better to let people answer this question in my opinion

Comment: Or you could use the Share button to link to that specific answer. We don't need multiple questions solving the same problem.

Comment: This is a different problem though, anyway here is that solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4492689/13456082